# SMO backup reports can't open backup device (which is a file), Message 3201

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5, shared-hosting, smo

This code runs fine on a local SQL Server Express instance:

```
Dim thisSMOBackup As New Backup()
With thisSMOBackup
  .Database = singleDatabase.Name 'This contains the database name
  .Action = BackupActionType.Database
  .Devices.AddDevice(DatabaseFileName, DeviceType.File)
  .Incremental = False
  .LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate
End With
Try
  thisSMOBackup.SqlBackup(thisServer) 'thisServer is setup w/ valid connection string and reads back data OK from the SQL server
  System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfileName, singleDatabase.Name & " - backed up")
Catch ex As Exception
  System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfileName, singleDatabase.Name & " - " & ex.InnerException.Message & vbCrLf)
End Try
```

When I apply the same code to a shared hosting SQL Server, it yields the following inner exception error message:

> Cannot open backup device 'D:\aFolderName\aBackupName\theDatabaseName.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.). BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>   Message #: 3201

There seems to be different ways to connect to the servers. For the SQL Server Express instance, I am using the `.ServerInstance` property, for the hosted server I am using the `.ConnectionString` property. Does that have anything to do with how the SMO code functions?

I have read that shared SQL hosting servers can have restrictions that are difficult to get past, but before I give up I wanted to ask for input.

The error itself suggests SMO can't find the location to write the file, but it's there, and I set the security for the folder to "Everyone" with "Full Control".  But then errors seem to not always mean precisely what they say. I wondered if there were some other parameters I need to setup for this operation to succeed, or other places to look.

Comment: I think I get it.  Does this mean when my local app accesses SMO, the SMO is actually running on the remote SQL server and not on my local machine?  That I'm merely interfacing to that server and it's doing the work there?  Assuming so, it would seem there's no way to get SMO backups sent locally, but I'll ask anyway in case I'm missing something obvious; are there any techniques I could use to push the backups to my machine?  The hosting service does have some backup capabilities, but they're manual & I was trying to do this in local code.

Comment: No, not so much... Like everyone else I go to great lengths to keep people **off my machines!**  But since I'm only a moderate level coder I find there are often known or proven techniques to solve problems like this that I've never been exposed too; but apparently not this problem.  I will spend some time trying to see if I can use the hosting provider's ftp services in case that might solve the problem in a way I was hoping for.  Nicely focused help, though.  Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're trying to create a backup in your shared hosting environment, the backup file is being written to the file system **of that remote server machine** (**NOT** your own, local `D:` drive!) where your SQL Server is running.

Most likely, the user account that runs the SQL Server remotely just doesn't have permission to write to that directory.

Also: this is a *good thing*! After all, you wouldn't want a remote server machine which you don't know and have no control over to be able to have direct write access to your own, local machine - now would you?

What you *could* do (esp. in a corporate environment) is to write backups to a **UNC path** (`\\server\share\path`) where both the remote SQL Server machine has **write access** to, and to which you have at least read access, so that you could go there and copy the `.bak` files to your local machine as needed. With a commercial hosting company, that option very rarely exists, however....